Unable to route traffc from home lab to internet
Good afternoon. I am running several devices in my HomeLab network, and that network connects to my home network through my Raspberry Pi (<-- my first Pi and it works really well). Connectivity between those two networks is working well.
Now I'm trying to route traffic from my home lab to the internet and not having much luck. Per an article I read I tried using 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 as netmask and gateway for the the traffic, but no joy. I don't have DNS configured at this time, but I can't even ping anything on the internet by IP address. Can anyone point me to an article somewhere that will help me with this issue?
NOTE: I'm running Ubuntu 23.10 on the Pi, but the forum won't let me put that in the "Tags" section.
Thanks,
Joe
